# How to install Solfege?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I need to install [Solfege](https://solfeg.io/), which needs [MMA](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mma.1.html) and other complements. How do I install it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fellow musician and never knew that this program existed until your question--Good find!

Anyways, to install the program, open up Terminal and enter this command:

`sudo apt-get install solfege`

And it SHOULD install. If it doesn't, let me know in the comments below...I sense that there may be something else wrong.